# How do I use Python/openpyxl to create collapsible rows/columns in Excel that can be collapsed?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, xlrd

I have a spreadsheet that I created using Python and openpyxl, and I'm trying to create collapsible columns that look like this: [image]
I know which row and column numbers I want to make collapsible. Intended functionality is that whenever anyone opens the Excel file, they should be able to click the (-) and (+) buttons to expand and collapse rows.

I don't even know is this possible (if Excel provides this as a modifiable attribute that some code could edit), but if it is - how do I achieve this using Python?

Comment: I believe using https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.worksheet.dimensions.html

Comment: You want to use outlines and groups.